# Probability that you get a response to a request for a document

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working on a project where I am running a number of different approaches to request documentation for products. I am able to get the documents from 2 different, independent sources.

When I ask Source 1: I get a valid document 20% of the time
When I ask source 2: I get a valid document 70% of the time.

I want to calculate the overall response rate, is P(1) + P(2) = 90% correct?

REFINING QUESTION BASED ON FEEDBACK:

The following formula is helpful to answer the question: P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B)

Meaning they are dependent events, therefore you would need to subtract the intersection ( when both A and B are true), would it just be the 20% for A? My confusion is if this were rolling dice and P(A) is landing on 3 so1/6 and P(B) is landing on an odd number is 3/6. The intersect is when both A and B land on 3. In this case I don't know when they will respond for the same product so how do I define the intersection ( −P(A∩B)l). That's why originally I misunderstood I can calculate as independent and just add them...

Comment: The following formula is helpful to answer the question: $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: No.  Suppose both sources were successful $70\%$ of the time.  Would you conclude that the answer was $140\%$?

Comment: @Callculus42 so for dependent events, you would subtract thr intersection ( when both A and B are true), would it just be the 20% for A? My confusion is if this were rolling dice and P(A) is landing on 3  so1/6 and P(B) is landing on an odd number is 3/6. The intersect is when both A and B land on 3. In this case I don't know when they will respond for the same product so how do I define the −P(A∩B) part. That's why originally I misunderstood I can calculate as independent and just add them..

Comment: You'll need to assume or define some overlap to calculate an answer. Without knowing more all, we can say is the probability is somewhere between 70% (if the first source is only correct when the second is also correct) and 90% (if the first source is only correct when the second is not). We can't say any more without knowing anything about the joint probability of both sources together being correct. You mention the sources are independent, is that true in a statistical sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For dependent events, you would subtract the intersection ( when both
> A and B are true), would it just be the 20% for A?

Not really. The formula is $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. So in general it is not true that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$, if $P(A) \leq  P(B)$. If the events A and B are disjoint, then $P(A\cap B)=0$.

> My confusion is if this were rolling dice and P(A) is landing on 3
> so 1/6 and P(B) is landing on an odd number is 3/6. The intersect is
> when both A and B land on 3

Yes, that is true. So $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)=\frac16+\frac12-\frac16=\frac12$.

Here we have the case where $A$ is a subset of $B$. Thus $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$.

[image]

To answer your initial question

> I am working on a project where I am running a number of different
> approaches to request documentation for products. I am able to get the
> documents from 2 different, independent sources.
>
> When I ask Source 1: I get a valid document 20% of the time When I ask
> source 2: I get a valid document 70% of the time.

The sources are independent. That means that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$. So the probability that at least one of the two sources send a valid document is

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)\cdot P(B)$

$=0.2+0.7-0.2\cdot 0.7=0.9-0.14=0.76=76\%$

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: @Samatar It pleases me that all is clear. You're welcome.